# What method should be included in the class

Tags: c#, design-patterns, code-structure

I'm confused what type of methods should be included in the class and what type of methods should be write in a service class?

This is my scenario:

I'm writing a music store app, and my models designed as below

```
 public class Album
{
    private string title;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }

    private double price;

    public double Price
    {
        get { return price; }
        set { price = value; }
    }

    private List<Music> musicFiles;

    public List<Music> MusicFiles
    {
        get { return musicFiles; }
        set { musicFiles = value; }
    }


}

public class Music
{
    private string title;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }

    private string duration;

    public string Duration
    {
        get { return duration; }
        set { duration = value; }
    }

}
```

Users can do such operations:

1. Download a whole album or some specific music files;
2. Delete local files;
3. Add album to favorite list;
4. Remove album from favorite list.

Should I put methods such as Dwonload in the model or in another service class? If I put them in the model, the model should reference some other classes. My current solutions are:

**solution1**: create IDownload/IFavorite interface and let the model implement them, the methods are included in the model;

**solution2**: create a abstract class which contains all the properties which related to download operation and favorite operation; let models inherite from the abstract class; create DownloadService class and FavoriteService class to implement the details of the operations, pass the argument like below:

```
AbstractClass obj1 = new MusicFile();
AbstractClass obj2 = nwe Album();
```

Which solution is sensible, or is there any other solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: Solution 3: Make a `FavoriteList` class that has add/remove methods for `Album`s; make a service class that has `DownloadAlbum` and `DownloadSong` methods, and whatever else is needed for the local files stuff.

Comment: @poke Seperate methods for DownloadAlbum and DownloadSong would only be useful if the implementation would be different.

Comment: @Georg Just because your *interface* has different methods, that does not mean that the implementation is separate or may not share e.g. a common file download.

Comment: @poke & Georg, Thanks for your reply. DownloadAlbum is only iterate through the music files and download them.

Answer (score 1):

Also a better of calling your music artifact download, so you have ability to change or add new artifact without changing the downloading caller interfaces. This is as of my understanding about question.

Please consider this is pseudo code and write your own java code with proper syntax.

```
//Client call

DownloadStore  store  = new DownloadStore(myMusicfile)

store.download();

DownloadStore  store  = new DownloadStore(myAlbum)

store.download();


//your download store
DownloadStore {

IMusicArtifact artifact;

DownloadStore(IMusicArtifact  artifact){
  this.artifact=artifact;
}

public downlod(){

//write common coding for any artifact...

//artifact specific implemenation is called here
artifact.download();

}

}


//your interface class
IMusicArtifact {

download();

}


//your concrete class
Muscifile implements IMusicArtifact {


download(){
// Music file related downloaind stuff
}

}


//your concrete class
Album implements IMusicArtifact {

download(){
// Album related downloaind stuff
}


}
```

Comment: This is my first solution. :) But download method in the model should reference some other infrastructure class

Comment: I believe infrastructure means back end file system (ftp, OS file system etc), if so yes you are correct. I prefer this solution since it help us add any artifact to the download interface without changing client calls.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest solution would be a decicated service class, e.g. "Downloader". If Download is a frequently used operation, you may introduce a facade on the music file class or one of its base classes to improve the code understandability.

The answer to your question whether to put the download method in interfaces or in an abstract base class depends on how you think these operations will be used. If you access for instance the download operation primarily as an ability, e.g. you want to download a lot of stuff and don't really care what these items are, then an interface is the best choice. The reason for this is that an interface does not restrict your inheritance hierarchy, whereas an abstract base class does.

An abstract base class is good if you can share the implementation of operations across multiple files. So if downloading an album is the same code as downloading a music file, an abstract class with a shared implementation is more appropriate.

Often, you use objects based on their ability to do certain stuff and the implementation of this stuff is indeed shared. In that case, the best way is to use an interface and a separate abstract base class that contains the shared code. This way, you use the advantages of both an interface and an abstract base class. If you look in the BCL, e.g. in ADO.NET a lot of concepts are implemented this way.